# How to add custom parameter to pip create environment in VS code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip

I inherited a python project which needs some dependencies from a non-default repo. I want to add a custom parameter (address of the repo) to the .venv creation action in VSCode.

The project uses pip. Adding `-f https://address.of.repo/stable.html` to the `pip install ...` command successfully builds the .venv from the command line (gitbash on windows 10), but I can't for the life of me find how to add the same parameter to the `Create Environment` VSCode action.

Comment: then create the `venv` in the command line in git bash

Comment: Using the create environment command in VSCode can only create a simple venv interpreter. You can manually create it in the command line and select it directly in VSCode.